# Guards: Isn't it true the we can replace them if "if" - "else if" - "else" without any significant drawbacks?

Tags: programming-practices

There are a lot of examples over Internet that show why you should use guards.

For example:

```
public double getPayAmount() {
  if (isDead){
    return deadAmount();
  }
  if (isSeparated){
    return separatedAmount();
  }
  if (isRetired){
    return retiredAmount();
  }
  return normalPayAmount();
}
```

The author compares the above version with

```
public double getPayAmount() {
  double result;
  if (isDead){
    result = deadAmount();
  }
  else {
    if (isSeparated){
      result = separatedAmount();
    }
    else {
      if (isRetired){
        result = retiredAmount();
      }
      else{
        result = normalPayAmount();
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

... and of course, the first one looks better.

But the author (*all* of the authors) ignores the fact that the first version can be changed to

```
public double getPayAmount() {
  if (isDead){
    return deadAmount();
  }
  else if (isSeparated){
    return separatedAmount();
  }
  else if (isRetired){
    return retiredAmount();
  }
  else {
    return normalPayAmount();
  }
}
```

which is not that ugly (compared to the second one).

And it makes me wonder whether guards are really so useful as authors trying to convince me. Could you show the case where guards are *really* make the code *much* better?

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat I know my question is bad. I simply don't understand where to get the required information. Have spent two days trying to find or create some good example without any success. There is a very small number of good articles about guards and all of them ignores the described issue.

Comment: I for one would argue the third example is better, because it ensures that every condition returns a value, but that's because this is a good situation to use switch/match, and a bad situation to use guards.

Comment: @VisualMelon "this is a good situation to use switch/match, and a bad situation to use guards" - Exactly! The problem is that all of the authors demonstrate the use of guards using the examples where "switch/case" is enough.

Comment: The logic here is not the same as switch match.  With the booleans, more than one can be true at a time, and the if-then code structure prioritizes them.  Ideally, there would be an enum { dead, separated, retired } where only one of these conditions can be true at once.  That would be ideal for switch/match.

Comment: @ErikEidt ah, yeah, I'd totally missed how non-exclusive these are. None-the-less, I'd still prefer an (ordered) matching for the reason described.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't even an example of guard clauses. Guard clauses are generally for "if this unwanted condition exists, exit early and don't execute this function". This example is instead more of a strategy, as in "return different values based on certain conditions". This is why true guard clauses are typically "if(x) return y", because they're not generally any more complicated than that.

Comment: Hmm curious how they also didn’t include `wait(0)` on every other line.

Comment: The third example is a guard pattern as well, as far as I'm concerned. The point of using the guard pattern is that you should return or raise inside the guard clause, rather than forcing single-exit and causing unnecessary nesting. Flat is better than nested. Using else-if statement, however, adds an extra else-keyword on every guards and an extra indentation on the last else block, which carries no additional value as guard blocks should always exit the function. So the first style of writing guards are preferred by most people using the guard pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an example from *Implementation Patterns* book by Kent Beck](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1149121&seqNum=11):

```
// version without guards
void compute() {
  Server server= getServer();
  if (server != null) {
    Client client= server.getClient();
    if (client != null) {
      Request current= client.getRequest();
      if (current != null)
        processRequest(current);
    }
  }
}
```

```
// version with guards
void compute() {
  Server server= getServer();
  if (server == null)
    return;
  Client client= server.getClient();
  if (client == null)
    return;
  Request current= client.getRequest();
  if (current == null)
    return;
  processRequest(current);
}
```

It seems this is exactly what I searched for. There are only 2 ways to write this function and the second one (i.e., with guards) is really better.

Comment: Swift: if let server = getServer(), let client = server.getClient(), let current = client.getRequest() { processRequest(current) } Or you can use a guard statement for all three required conditions. Much less code to write.

Comment: @gnasher729 Did you mean this: https://pastebin.com/raw/53VDem1i? I suppose the longer version from Kent's book is better if we want to return different values, e.g. `return "Server not found"`, `return "Client not found"`, `return "Current request failed"`.

Comment: No, exactly as written. “If let” in Swift checks if an optional result is non-nil and unwraps it, and can contain multiple such checks separated by comma. The unwrapped optionals server, client, current are only available within the “if let” statement.

Answer (score 2):

> And it makes me wonder whether guards are really so useful as authors trying to convince me. Could you show the case where guards are really make the code much better?

Your example is biased because it uses `return` inside the `if` bodies, forcing the method to end when it enters an `if`. This pretty much excludes the relevance of any code *after* the `else` of any `if` statement that evaluates to `true`.

If you don't use `return`, then `if .. if ..` and `if .. else if .. else` behave **very differently**.

```
public double getPayAmount() {
  var result = 0;

  if (isDead){
    result += 100;
  }
  else if (isSeparated){
    result += 50;
  }
  else if (isRetired){
    result + = 25;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Assuming all booleans are true, without the `else` it'd return 175, with the `else` it'd return 100.

---

> But the author (all of the authors) ignores the fact that the first version can be changed to

Sure, you *could* use it, but that doesn't mean that it must be mentioned. When you use returning if bodies, the `else` is **irrelevant**. There's no point to having it.

Using simple step through debugging is going to explain it much better than a written answer will.

The short answer here is that for any `if` which returns in its body, the `else` can be removed without changing the flow of the code, therefore makking it irrelevant to write an `else`.

Comment: If the conditional block doesn't exit the function (i.e. return or raise), that's just a regular conditional branch, not a guard. The raison d'etre for a guard statement is that because you know the guard block always exits the function, you can just assume that any following blocks don't need to deal with the situation that the guard is protecting against.